# Small belt transmission: Radius difference?

Tags: pulleys, transmission

I am trying to make a pulley reduction system for my project. I need it to be as quiet as possible, so I am considering pulleys.

My project also has limited space, so I am trying to have as small a pulley on one end as possible. For example, [this](https://www.technobotsonline.com/8mm-miniature-plastic-model-pulley.html) is a pulley with 4mm radius. I think I've even found with 3mm radius.

For such small radii, the difference between the innermost and the outermost part of a pulley is significant. Let us assume the following pulley:

[image]

In that case, what radius should I assume to calculate transmission speed? How does the belt actually work?

Comment: There are pulleys for timing belts, flat belts, and V-belts. That looks like V-belt pulley and V-belts are trapezoidal, not V-shaped so don't go all the way into the valley. EDIT: Well that's for an O-ring but same idea. You basically have the rod in a V-groove with two points of contact if you ignore deformation, but that probably isn't valid here.

Comment: Small pulleys that I have had  (8 mm movie projectors, etc) used coiled steel spring  belts. I don't know the reason but I expect there is one.

Comment: A belt is a poor choice if you need constant speed.  As the belt wears the radius changes.  Also be careful because small diameter pulleys have very limited contact area and are prone to slip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would estimate The radius to be a bit larger than 4 mm. How much, depends on the friction and stiffness of your belt. Similar to continuously variable transmission, CVT.

If the belt is stiff enough and is not going to fill the grove fast, it will rotate around a circle a bit bigger than 4mm. If it is flexible and has less friction it will hug the pully and 4mm is the radius.

If you tighten the belt by a 3rd free turning pulley the radius will get very close to 4mm.

[image: CVT]